# How can I find what SVN branch my git branch will dcommit to?

Tags: git, git-svn

How can I check what branch "svn dcommit" from my currently checked out branch is going to push to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git svn info` will include the URL of the Subversion repo your git branch tracks.

```
$ git svn info
Path: .
URL: svn+ssh://svn.example.com/myRepository/myProject/trunk
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git svn dcommit --dry-run` to see what will happen when you dcommit.